# How do I simplify bash's 'eval "$TIME $BIN_FILE $BIN_OPTS &> $LOG_FILE"' and keep it working?

Tags: bash, shell, eval

I'm updating a bash script which serves as a program testing tool.
Previously, I had this line in a script working perfectly (`$BIN_FILE` is set to a relative path to the binary being tested):

```
$BIN_FILE $BIN_OPTS &> $LOG_FILE
```

Then I've decided to add some "performance measurements":

```
time $BIN_FILE $BIN_OPTS &> $LOG_FILE"
```

This worked perfectly as well, but when running many tests at once, script's output was too crowded with all those "real, user, system". Now I'm passing a second parameter to the script, which causes $TIME variable to have value 'time' assigned to it. However,

```
$TIME $BIN_FILE $BIN_OPTS &> $LOG_FILE
```

just doesn't work. The only working option seems to be

```
eval "$TIME $BIN_FILE $BIN_OPTS &> $LOG_FILE"
```

but it's ugly.

Why doesn't

```
$TIME $BIN_FILE $BIN_OPTS &> $LOG_FILE
```

work? Is there a nicer-looking solution, then the one with *eval*?

Also, regarding portability - should I use bash's internal 'time', or call GNU /usr/bin/time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`time` is a reserved word in bash. It must be written explicitly because it is parsed before parsing the "[simple commands](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Simple-Commands)", and therefore before variable substitutions. For example, you cannot use builtin `time` in this way:

```
cat long-file | time sort
```

It has to be:

```
time cat long-file | sort
```

and here `bash` will measure time spend by whole pipeline.

`GNU time` is a simple binary, so it can be used in the way you mean it... and it can be used in the middle of a pipeline. But it is not always installed, so I guess you'd better use builtin.

I guess you want to omit `time` in some specific cases and because of that you want variable substitution. If so, you can go with `GNU time`, `eval` or some kind of `if..fi` structure, but you definitely cannot use builtin the way you wanted.

If you want to be more portable, you should use its `-p` option to get the same output under different implementations. See f.e. [OpenGroup's `time` description](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/time.html). Then whatever implementation you choose, it should behave the same way (as long as it is POSIX-compliant).

Answer (score 1):

You may find it helpful to use a shorter format for the output of `time`:

```
$ /usr/bin/time -f "Real %E" sleep 1
Real 0:01.02
$ TIMEFORMAT="Real %R"
$ time sleep 1        # Bash builtin
Real 1.027
```

The output of either version of `time` can be further customized (less so for the Bash builtin).

Comment: thanks, I didn't now that besides the only accepted -p option I can use TIMEFORMAT to modify Bash builtin display format.