# Filter time(1) output to get time values only

Tags: macos, shell, awk, zsh

how do I filter certain time command output values under OS X?
I have tried

```
➜  ~  (time ls -la)| grep system|awk "{print $4, $6, $8, $10}"
ls -G -la  0.01s user 0.01s system 16% cpu 0.102 total
```

however I want to take only numbers, in this case "0.01 0.01 16 0.102"
Thanks

Edit: Paul pointed out, that output might [go to stderr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818255/in-the-bash-shell-what-is-21) so my solution is to "redirect" output to stdout and continue hacking strings :)

```
(time ls -la) 2>&1 | grep system | tr -dc '[:digit:]. '
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using the zsh builtin `time`, set the variable `TIMEFMT` to control the output (see `man zshparam`).

To reproduce the default output without the alpha strings:

```
TIMEFMT='%*E %*U %*S %P'
```

The asterisks prevent the output of `s` for "seconds", for example.

You can, of course, limit it to one particular field if that's all you're really interested in.

Redirect the output of time to capture it in a variable or process it further:

```
duration=$({ time ls -la >/dev/null; } 2>&1)
```

I redirected the output of the command to `/dev/null`, but if you want to capture it just remove that redirection.

Comment: For Bash, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3686395/26428) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3929399/26428) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1767669/26428).

Answer (score 2):

The generic answer here is that in order to process the output of `time` in general you must have a construct like

```
(time command 1>/dev/null) 2>&1 | ...
```

Which times the command in a subshell and hides its output, then captures the output of time (which is on stderr, aka descriptor 2) and redirects it to stdout, then directs stdout to a pipe. After that further processing is possible.

As Dennis Williamson noted, zsh's TIMEFMT can be used to customize the output. This is nice because it means you probably don't have to construct a pipeline to reformat time's output when using zsh, but you still have to do the stderr redirection to capture the output.

Answer (score 1):

Bit of a hack, but you could just remove non-numeric characters?

```
tr -dc '[:digit:]. '
```

EDIT: Also, the output may be going to stderr so redirect it to stdin with 2>&1

Comment: If you mean (time ls -la) | grep system|tr -dc '[:digit:]. ' I still get the same result. Time output seems to be somewhat mysterious and immune to piping...

Comment: Thanks, Paul, you pointed me out to a right direction. Though I can not mark your answer as accepted cause it's not complete. You can edit it if you want and I will accept it. Thanks a lot ;)